# Aggregating / Concatening character value of same IDs rows

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am a R beginner and currently facing a problem I can't conceptualize for now.
I have looked several related posts but have not find a specific answer except there
 :
[Aggregating rows with same Ids and retaining only unique entries in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057781/aggregating-rows-with-same-ids-and-retaining-only-unique-entries-in-r)

but my problem is a bit different.

Here's the structure of the initial df I wanna use :

sta_RHP_metho (3528,4) the variables are :
- "code.sandre" witch is the ID i'll use
- "CodeOpera" a unique id witch is related to "code.sandre"
- "Methode.de.peche" a character vector
- "year"

In that df there's as much rows as unique "CodeOpera" (3528). There are several "CodeOpera" by id/"code.sandre" and there are 180 code.sandre

What i want to get is a df with a unique row by "code.sandre" and the "Methode.de.peche" character value for each year.

I almost got that by processing the following code :

```
x2<-melt(sta_RHP_metho,c("code.sandre","CodeOpera","year"),"Methode.de.peche")
x3<-as.data.frame(dcast(x2,code.sandre + CodeOpera ~ year))
```

But I still have several as much rows as unique "CodeOpera" (3528) and as I said I don't know how to get a unique rox by ID.
A thing to notice is that it's possible to have several "Methode.de.peche" by year so i may need to concatenate returned values in some case.

Hope my explanations are clear.

Comments will be greatly appreciated ;)

Cheers.

Tristan

---

Thank you  @ANG. Here's minimal reproducible example:

1/The dataframe I got after my melt/dcast operation :

```
code_sandre<-c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D")
year1<-c("a",NA,"a","b",NA,"c","b") 
year2<-c("a","b",NA,"b","b","c","b") 
year3<-c("a","b",NA,NA,NA,"c","b")
x<-data.frame(v1 =code.sandre,v2 =year1,v3 =year2, v4 =year3))
```

2/The dataframe I wanna get:

```
code_sandre<-c("A","B","C","D")
year1<-c("a","b",NA,"b")
year2<-c("a,b","b","c","b")
year3<-c("a,b",NA,"c","b")
result<-data.frame(code_sandre,year1,year2,year3)
```

Comment: Hello Tristan and welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I got you right but it looks like you just want unique `code.sandre` no matter the value of `CodeOpera`. Do you get the expected result after trying this (check the result before using `melt()`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sta_RHP_metho)
# delete column "CodeOpera"
sta_RHP_metho <- sta_RHP_metho[, CodeOpera := NULL]
# take unique rows
library(dplyr)
sta_RHP_metho2 <- distinct(sta_RHP_metho)
```

OR

What I was able to achieve.

```
code_sandre<-c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D")
year1<-c("a",NA,"a","b",NA,"c","b") 
year2<-c("a","b",NA,"b","b","c","b") 
year3<-c("a","b",NA,NA,NA,"c","b")
x<-data.frame(code_sandre =code_sandre,
              year1 = year1,
              year2 = year2,
              year3 = year3)
library(dplyr)
x2 <- x %>%
        group_by(code_sandre) %>%
        summarise_at(.vars = vars(year1, year2, year3),
                     .funs = function(x) toString(unique(x[!is.na(x)])))
x2
x3 <- as.data.frame(x2)
x3[x3 == ""] <- NA
x3
```

I think it should be very close to your expected output.

Comment: Try this to see `sta_RHP_metho2 <- as.data.frame(sta_RHP_metho2)` and then use `melt()`.

Comment: That is almost what I want but I can't do the melt from your `sta_RHP_metho2 <- distinct(sta_RHP_metho)` and that is not the dataframe structure I want in output. Efectively I want a unique row per `"code.sandre"` and a unique column by `"year"`observed in my initial dataframe. For each junction between a row and a column, 3 possibilies :    no value (because no sampling that year), 1 value (because 1 unique `"Methode.de.peche"` even if several `"CodeOpera"`in that year), several values (several `"Methode.de.peche"`). Maybe the dataframe is not appropriate in my case ? matrix ?

Comment: Sorry for my messy comments I will improve my syntax